# Clean importing of python submodules

Tags: python

I have an directory like this

```
test.py
foo/__init__.py
foo/bar.py
```

and in the bar.py a simple function:

```py
def say_stuff()
    print("Stuff")
```

And want to call it from the Test.py like this:

```py
import foo
foo.bar.say_stuff()
```

Then i get the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'foo' has no attribute 'bar'

I know to at least fix that error by editing the __init __.py

```py
from .bar import *
```

But then both of those approaches work:

```
foo.bar.say_stuff()
foo.say_stuff()
```

Now my question, how do i get only the foo.bar.say_stuff() to work.
I dont want to load every thing into foo, already beacuse i want clean auto_complete suggestions from my IDE.

Is there any source you can recommend to **properly** learn pythons import system. All the tutaorals seem too basic and always run into unexpected behavior.

Comment: `import foo.bar`. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change from:

```
from .bar import *
```

to:

```
import foo.bar
```

This behavior is described here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules